# Trigonometry Equation (Need hints)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve $\tan x \cos2x=\frac{1}{5}$ for $0^\circ<x<360^\circ$

Can I get some hints for solving this trigonometry equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may get some results if you set $ u = \tan \frac{x}{2} $. Then $\cos x = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and $\sin x = \frac{2u}{1+u^2} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting $t=\tan x$:

$$t\cdot \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=\frac 15\\
5t^3+t^2-5t+1=0\\
t=-1.1857,0.22043,0.76524$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the identity $\tan^2x+1 = \sec^2 x$ and that $\cos2x=2\cos^2 x-1$:
$$t\cdot(2c^2-1)=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$t\cdot\left(\frac{2}{t^2+1}-1\right) = \frac{1}{5}$$